# Save all cookies from first page in text file on hard disk

Tags: javascript, file, cookies, text, save

I need to save all cookies from first page in text file on hard disk.

How to do this with javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For security reasons you cannot use javascript to read/write files on the client computer. You can [read/write cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) which could be persistent and if they are persistent they are actually stored by the browser on the client computer but the way and location this is done is out of your control.

Comment: What about user input, if I have 2-3 textboxes can I save it in text file on hard disk user input from these textboxes?

Comment: @Ivan Tanasijevic, no you can't save this input into a file on the client computer. You can save it on your server.

Comment: I am talking about client computer, not server.

Comment: @Ivan Tanasijevic, then I already gave you the answer: no, you cannot write to files on the client computer using javascript.